# Why does the object appear before animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, core-plot

I implemented `corePlot` in my `xcode` project. I use the pie chart, and I tried animating it like this:

```
[CPTAnimation animate:pieChart property:@"endAngle" from:pieChart.startAngle + M_PI * 2 to:pieChart.startAngle  duration:2.0];
```

It animates well, but the problem is, as soon as the chart is supposed to be displayed, (before the animation,) the chart shows for a split second then disappears and starts the animation.

How can I get it to start the animation without it appearing before hand?

**Update**

Here is the full code:

```
CPTGraph *graph = self.hostView.hostedGraph;
self.pieChart = [[CPTPieChart alloc] init];
self.pieChart.dataSource = self;
self.pieChart.delegate = self;
self.pieChart.pieRadius = (self.hostView.bounds.size.height * 0.7) / 2;
self.pieChart.identifier = graph.title;
self.pieChart.endAngle = self.pieChart.startAngle;
self.pieChart.pieInnerRadius = self.pieChart.pieRadius / 2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When configuring the plot, set the initial `endAngle` to the same value as the `startAngle`. The default of `NAN` tells the plot to draw a full circle starting from the `startAngle`.

Comment: Sorry for keep on bothering you! (I'm a beginner in objective-c and corePlot.) I did the following `pieChart.endAngle = pieChart.startAngle;` And I get the same effect?

Comment: Look at the "Donut Chart" demo in the *Plot Gallery* example app. It animates the outer ring spreading out from vertical (start and end angles == π/2) and then the radius of the inner circle after a delay. I don't see an initial flash of drawing the full ring, even when I remove the animation.

Comment: The flashing only happens when I apply the animation. Maybe the way I implemented the animation is wrong?

Comment: You need to animate from the `startAngle` to the new ending value.